# How to Fix Wordpress 500 Internal server error due to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, 500-internal-error

I am using couponXL theme for my site. Everything is working correct but except one ie., custom post type. In the theme , there is a plugin called CouponXL custom post type. This plugin is included to enable custom post type feature for the theme.

Whenever I activate this plugin, server is responding with 500 internal server error. When I deactivate the plugin, server is running with no issue. So the issue must be with the custom post type.

When I looked into the server error logs. I found the following error,

```
] [notice] EACCELERATOR(810915): PHP crashed on opline 28 of array_merge() at /home/teachpkc/public_html/offers/wp-includes/functions.php:3076
] [notice] EACCELERATOR(803175): PHP crashed on opline 28 of array_merge() at /home/teachpkc/public_html/offers/wp-includes/functions.php:3076
```

Here is the plugin code for the custom post type

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Coupon XL Custom Post Types
Plugin URI: http://demo.powerthemes.club/themes/couponxl/
Description: Coupon XL custom post types and taxonomies
Version: 1.0
Author: pebas
Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/pebas/
License: GNU General Public License version 3.0
*/

if( !function_exists( 'couponxl_post_types_and_taxonomies' ) ){
    function couponxl_post_types_and_taxonomies(){
        $offer_args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Offers', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Offer', 'couponxl' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'author',
                'excerpt',
                'comments'
            )
        );
        if( class_exists('ReduxFramework') && function_exists('couponxl_get_option') ){
            $trans_offer = couponxl_get_option( 'trans_offer' );
            if( !empty( $trans_offer ) ){
                $offer_args['rewrite'] = array( 'slug' => $trans_offer );
            }
        }
        register_post_type( 'offer', $offer_args ); 

        register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'offer' ), array(
            'label' => __( 'Location', 'couponxl' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                          => __( 'Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name'                 => __( 'Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'menu_name'                     => __( 'Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'all_items'                     => __( 'All Locations', 'couponxl' ),
                'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'view_item'                     => __( 'View Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Location Name', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Location', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item_colon'             => __( 'Parent Location:', 'couponxl' ),
                'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Locations', 'couponxl' ),
                'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Locations', 'couponxl' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate locations with commas', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove locations', 'couponxl' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from the most used locations', 'couponxl' ),
                'not_found'                     => __( 'No locations found', 'couponxl' ),
            )

        ) );


        register_taxonomy( 'offer_cat', array( 'offer' ), array(
            'label' => __( 'Offer Categories', 'couponxl' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                          => __( 'Offer Categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name'                 => __( 'Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'menu_name'                     => __( 'Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'all_items'                     => __( 'All Offer Categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'view_item'                     => __( 'View Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Offer Category Name', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Offer Category', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item_colon'             => __( 'Parent Offer Category:', 'couponxl' ),
                'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Offer Categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Offer Categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate offer categories with commas', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove offer categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from the most used offer categories', 'couponxl' ),
                'not_found'                     => __( 'No offer categories found', 'couponxl' ),
            )

        ) );

        register_taxonomy( 'offer_tag', array( 'offer' ), array(
            'label' => __( 'Offer Tags', 'couponxl' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                          => __( 'Offer Tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name'                 => __( 'Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'menu_name'                     => __( 'Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'all_items'                     => __( 'All Offer Tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'view_item'                     => __( 'View Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Offer Tag Name', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Offer Tag', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item_colon'             => __( 'Parent Offer Tag:', 'couponxl' ),
                'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Offer Tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Offer Tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate offer tags with commas', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove offer tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from the most used offer tags', 'couponxl' ),
                'not_found'                     => __( 'No offer tags found', 'couponxl' ),
            )

        ) );

        $store_args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Stores', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Store', 'couponxl' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-store',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail'
            ),
        );
        if( class_exists('ReduxFramework') && function_exists('couponxl_get_option') ){
            $trans_store = couponxl_get_option( 'trans_store' );
            if( !empty( $trans_store ) ){
                $store_args['rewrite'] = array( 'slug' => $trans_store );
            }
        }
        register_post_type( 'store', $store_args ); 

        register_taxonomy( 'letter', array( 'store' ), array(
            'label' => __( 'Letters', 'couponxl' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'                          => __( 'Letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name'                 => __( 'Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'menu_name'                     => __( 'Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'all_items'                     => __( 'All Letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'view_item'                     => __( 'View Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Letter Name', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Letter', 'couponxl' ),
                'parent_item_colon'             => __( 'Parent Letter:', 'couponxl' ),
                'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate letters with commas', 'couponxl' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from the most used letters', 'couponxl' ),
                'not_found'                     => __( 'No letters found', 'couponxl' ),
            )

        ) );        

        register_post_type( 'voucher', array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Vouchers', 'couponxl' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Voucher', 'couponxl' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tickets-alt',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
            ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'publish_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'edit_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'edit_others_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'delete_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'delete_others_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'read_private_posts' => 'manage_options',
                'edit_post' => 'manage_options',
                'delete_post' => 'manage_options',
                'read_post' => 'manage_options',
            ),          
        ));

        if( class_exists( 'Seravo_Custom_Bulk_Action' ) ){
            $bulk_actions = new Seravo_Custom_Bulk_Action( array('post_type' => 'voucher') );

            $bulk_actions->register_bulk_action(array(
                'menu_text' => __( 'Pay To Sellers', 'couponxl' ),
                'admin_notice'=> __( 'Sellers are paid', 'couponxl' ),
                'callback' => function( $post_ids ) {
                    couponxl_pay_all_sellers( $post_ids, 'no' );
                    return true;
                }
            ));

            $bulk_actions->init();
        }

    }
}
add_action('init', 'couponxl_post_types_and_taxonomies', 0);

?>
```

I have tried all solutions in the net but couldn't solve :( Could you please help me, what is the error and how to fix it :)

**Note:** I am using this theme in a sub-domain. Don't know whether the problem could be because of this. To your information guys I've added

Comment: Seems like when I change the priority of add action('init') from 1 to 10. I am not getting internal server error. Can anyone shed me light on this behaviour.

Comment: looks like a problem with your opcode caching tool

Comment: Turn off EAccelerator, you might have problems with other things later. Try OPCACHE or APC on older PHP versions. Like Mark Kaplun suggested, the opcacheing extension for php that you use it's causing the issue.